# How to correctly Update Odoo / Openerp website context?

Tags: python, odoo

I trying to adapt the module https://www.odoo.com/apps/modules/9.0/website_sale_product_brand/ to have a select box on the shop page, and filter by brand and category, and not to have to go to a diferent page and select the brand.
In that module they update context with the brand_id so the sale_product_domain function could append to the domain. In the module, it filter it as a charm, but in my code not....

Any guest?
When I debug self.env.context in the sale_product_domain function not brand if append, but in the website_sale_product_brand yes, with the exactly same code

controller.py

```
class WebsiteSale(website_sale):
    @http.route(['/shop',
                 '/shop/page/<int:page>',
                 '/shop/category/<model("product.public.category"):category>',
                 '/shop/category/<model("product.public.category"):category>/page/<int:page>',
                 ],type='http',auth='public',website=True)
    def shop(self, page=0, category=None, search='', brand=None, **post):
        # Update context to modify sale_product_domain function from website model
        if brand:
            context = dict(request.env.context)
            context.setdefault('brand', int(brand))
            request.env.context = context

        result = super(WebsiteSale, self).shop(page=page, category=category,
                                             brand=brand, search=search,
                                             **post)

        #append brand to keep so links mantain brand filter
        keep = QueryURL('/shop',
                        brand=brand,
                        category=category and int(category),
                        search=search,)
                        #attrib=attrib_list TODO

        #Update result
        result.qcontext['keep'] = keep
        result.qcontext['brands'] = http.request.env['product.brand'].search([]) #use to populate template select box
        result.qcontext['sel_brand_id'] = brand #use to select the selected brand on brand select box

        return result
```

models.py

```
class WebSite(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'website'

    @api.multi
    def sale_product_domain(self):
        domain = super(WebSite, self).sale_product_domain()

        print self.env.context

        if 'brand' in self.env.context:
            domain.append(
                ('product_brand_id', '=', self.env.context['brand']))
        return domain
```

Comment: The context could be set from the view. Did you check it?

Comment: I need to set it from an url parameter.. .in this case brad=brand_id

Answer (score 0):

```py
ctx = dict (request.context)
ctx.update ({'bin_size': True})
request.context = ctx
```

That's it!